# django how to pull multiple querysets for a webpage

Tags: django

I am trying to get two querysets from my database to use in a webpage for my friend's bar. Right now all I have is two models, Alcohol and Drinks. I want to pull all the objects from both models and use in the same page. Is there something I can add to a ListView or do I need to create my own view for this? I have read a little on the itertools chain, but I don't know if this will do what I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking the generic class based views are best suited for a single model. Having said that, you can override [`get_context_data`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) and add any context you'd like. In your case let's add a second queryset:

```
from .models import Alcohol, Drinks

class AlcoholListView(ListView):
    model = Alcohol

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AlcoholListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context['drinks'] = Drinks.objects.all()

        return context
```

Comment: Awesome. That did exactly what I wanted it to do. Now I have to go in and filter the results so I can sort them in a submenu. Thanks for the help.